# COUNTIF formula based on today's date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

Suppose in `A1:A10` some dates are there and in `B1:B10` I am having some receipt number. I want to count all the receipt numbers for today's date in `A1:A10`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You should seriously considering studying up on this. Stack Overflow is not a site where you ask when you don't understand. At the very least, try it on your own. You've got a couple of issues now that shows you are incapable of simply changing a few conditions in ***one*** formula.

Comment: I am very much new in excel world so I tried in my own first and then i ask in this sight ....if i trouble u then i am really sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=TODAY())*(B1:B10<>""))
```

or, if your receipts column can't contain empty cells, just

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=TODAY())*1)
```

**UPD:**

> how should i use a start date and a end date in the same formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10>= DATE(2014,2,1))*(A1:A10<= DATE(2014,2,28))*(B1:B10<>""))
```

Comment: with sum product it calculate the hole number but i need the count of receipt ...how many receipt are r there in today's date

Comment: @ArindamSen, can you clarify what's wrong with formula and why it doesn't fit you?

Comment: suppose in A1:A10 dates r there and in B1:B10 some receipt number..so with sumproduct formula sum of all the receipt number of today's is reflecting..but i need the count ..not the sum

Comment: for count use this formula `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=TODAY())*1)` or `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=TODAY())*(B1:B10<>""))`

Comment: HI Simoco its done with =SUMPRODUCT((date=TODAY())*(QID<>""))...thnx a ton

Comment: Hi @simoco can you tell me  how should i use a start date and a end date in the same formula..example in row A1:A10, from 01/02/2014 to 28/02/2014 how many receipts number r there in B1:B10..

Comment: hi @Simoco ,in the same formula if i don't want to put any particular date then how to do it ...example in C1 I put one from date and in D1 I put To date ,so that i can change the date range any time... I have tried =COUNTIFS((date>=DATE(C1))*(date<=DATE(D1))*(B1:B10<>""))...can you help me out

Comment: just use `=COUNTIFS((date>=c1)*(date<=d1))*(B1:B10<>""))`

Comment: Suppose in A1:A10 dates r there and in B1:B10 some receipt number. So at that time when I want to count the receipt number of a particular date  formula was
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10>= DATE(2014,2,1))*(A1:A10<= DATE(2014,2,28))*(B1:B10<>""))
But now I want to put a date range suppose in C1 I put 01/02/2014 and D1 I put 28/02/2014.now I want to count the receipt number of B1:B10 in between date of C1 and D1 which is matching with A1:A10..how should I do this

Comment: I've already said it in prev comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10>= C1)*(A1:A10<= D1)*(B1:B10<>""))`

Comment: it should be in count ifs,coz i want to count the receipt number ...and if i relpace the sumproduct to countifs it is not working

Comment: you can't just replace sumproduct with countif. Countif has another approach of implementation. Use sumproduct - it will return _count_ of receipts

Comment: hi Simoco if u dont mind may I have you r mail ID...I need you r help very badly....plz plz plz

Comment: i have sent you a mail plz check it

Answer (score 3):

The following might suit:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,TODAY())
```

judging by a subsequent comment, named ranges are being used and allowance required for dates without receipts, so maybe:

```
=COUNTIFS(date,TODAY(),QID,"<>")
```

Comment: +1, I've updated my answer with this formula, but you beat me to it:)